# Formula field display blank value instead of a number

Tags: formula-field

I'm doing exercises on salesforce trailhead and created simple custom field of type Formula:

- field is created on Case object
- Formula Return Type: Number
- Decimal Places: 0
- Formula itself: TODAY() - Account.LastActivityDate
- Blank Field Handling: Treat blank fields as zeroes

This should give me number of days since last activity on account.
On case page I see the field, but it shows me blank value.

Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

I'm on developer edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably getting it blank because there are no ***Activity*** records on related Account. Could you please check if any activity is present on the related account?

For difference in Last Modified Date and Last Activity Date, check this link:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=What-is-the-difference-between-Last-Activity-and-Last-Modified-1327108315155&language=en_US